# Connect 3 monitors to Macbook Pro (2018) using one cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I want to have three external monitors connected to my Macbook Pro. I want to try keep it as neat as possible so, are there any hubs or ways I can connect three external monitors to my Macbook Pro with one cable?

Previously I've had two external monitors but an issue I ran into is how my Macbook would position the monitors every time I unplugged and plugged them back in (probably because my mac couldn't distinguish each monitor uniquely) so I want to try and avoid those kind of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can totally do this. Pick any AMD GPU that meets your needs - there are several that drive 3 to 6 displays in the $120 to $200 price point and put that in a thunderbolt 3 EGPU case.

- [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0745GHN53/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_tai_DT.yFbXV1S9X3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0745GHN53)

Pretty much anything you can put in a PCI slot will work over thunderbolt and one cable. Basically you’re putting a GPU for the new Mac Pro like the Radeon Pro W5500X MPX Module in an external enclosure.

- https://store.apple.com/xc/product/MXM52AM/A

Comment: Wonderful, I was hoping for a cheaper solution to tell you the truth but it might actually be a pretty cool setup having an eGPU. Thank you.

Comment: There are quite a few, and they are incredible - especially if you know just what you want GPU wise, @TimRowley

Comment: Also PSA - you probably want to avoid Nvidia unless you’re sure you can get compatible drivers for it. This is a bit of a bummer with [beasts like the RTX 3080 being released this fall.](https://www.tomsguide.com/news/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3080-revealed-release-date-price-specs-and-pre-order)